# How to answer all the things that NSLOG print out in a program to a MultiLIne Label?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nslog

I have a program consist of different classes and methods. In any part of my program I have put many `NSLog` that shows me the progress of my code.

I would like to show this in my cocoa program. In fact I want something like Console in XCODE that show everything which is coming out from `NSLog` .

How can I implement this in my own cocoa program?

Comment: If you do NSLog(), it will show in the output in XCode.  Can you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: i want to simulate the console of xcode inside my cocoa program, anything anywhere come out from nslog, it will be shown on my program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I easily redirect the console output in a NSTextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996110/how-can-i-easily-redirect-the-console-output-in-a-nstextview)

Answer (score 0):

NSLog sends text to the console via
stderr.  It is possible to redirect the console output ([How can I easily redirect the console output in a NSTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996110/how-can-i-easily-redirect-the-console-output-in-a-nstextview)), but this isn't the best approach in your case.

First, you shouldn't be using NSLog in production code. Use the Apple System Logger (directly via its C API or via one of the Objective-C wrappers such as the Google Toolbox for Mac).

Second, instead of redirecting stderr, read from the ASL database to populate your in-app log. Console messages are visible via ASL, so you can work with your existing NSLog code until you transition to ASL (see above) for logging.